# what is the package of the car() function in R

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I'm actually developping in R using RStudio. I just want to know in which package is located the function called car() which is used to extract the first element of a list .

Thanks

Comment: There are 1000s of packages for R so it's hard to know without any other information. If you have the package loaded and you just forget which package it is in, you can use `?car` but otherwise...

Comment: you can also type `car` at the command prompt, and after it prints the function code, the last line will be of the format <package: fuctionName>

Comment: Maybe you are refering to the custom function  [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html), which afaik is not part of any package.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what package it's in.  But here's how I'd go about finding out...

```
RSiteSearch("car", restrict = "functions")
```

or

```
library(sos)
findFn("car", sortby = "Function")
```

`apropos()` and `help.search()` are also worth looking into.

By the way, in general the first element in a list can be extracted with `[[1]]`